# Can't access SSRS folders on a local server following installation

Tags: reporting-services, certificate, ssrs-2019

*edit*
I also have the same problem as an admin on a domain

I just installed SSRS locally on a machine for and I cannot access the reports I deployed. Everything was installed as admin
when going to the web portal I get this massage

> Could not load folder contents
>
> You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions.

and when trying to access the web service via the config manager I get this one:

> The permissions granted to user <username> are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Additionally in the web portal I got no "manage" folder and only "my subscriptions" under the settings button .
Everything is running locally and as admin, the OS is windows 11 and the SSRS is version 15.0.1102.1002 and running in native mode.

I've looked all over the place and found out something about certificates, but almost everything in google is about access problems via remote server.

adding the URL to the trusted sites didn't help

Answer (score -1):

it certainly look like you don't have permission. Are you administrator? When you were installing did you set up some users to be administrators?
Find which account is administrator and then add yourself from the SSRS site. Is there another account you can run or Run as administrator?

Another way to install again.
If you decide to install again pay attention on the page with the users.

Comment: Everything was done and installed as an admin

Comment: that's great. But there is mapping with users during installation. May be your answer is there.

Comment: Down voting as this is an unhelpful answer, and the comment doesn't add anything.

I've just gone through installing SSRS 2022 (16.0.1114.11) multiple times as an admin user on my work laptop, am running into the same issue as the OP, and have found nothing online that helps as of yet.